# TClientDataSet não inicia

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, tclientdataset

Crio em tempo de execução um `TClientDataSet`, inicio, faço insert, porém em alguns computadores não inicia ou cria o `TClientDataSet`.

`Windows` do meu computador (Desenv) `Windows 7 32 bits`, funciona perfeitamente.

`Windows` do computador onde o erro se apresenta `Windows 7 64 Bits`, não cria o `TClientDataSet`.

Será que tem alguma coisa relativo a ser 32 ou 64 bits.

Parte do código:

```
if  dmPedido.cdsConexao.Active = false then
    dmPedido.cdsConexao.CreateDataSet;
dmPedido.cdsConexao.EmptyDataSet;
```

```
procedure TfrmTransmissao.MontaSequenciaConexao(fConexao:string);
var
    sParte,sParte2 : String;
    iInicio, i : Integer;
    //Definindo a entrada
    n: integer; //Conexao a ser utilizada
    S: String;  //Tipo do serviço
    E: String;  //Empresa
    p: integer; //Prioridade

procedure InsereItemTamporario (sEmp:Integer; sEnd:String; iPrior:Integer; sTpSer:String; iSeq:Integer);
begin
    try
        dmPedido.cdsConexao.Insert;
        dmPedido.cdsConexaoEmpresa.AsInteger    := sEmp;
        dmPedido.cdsConexaoEndereco.AsString    := sEnd;
        dmPedido.cdsConexaoPrioridade.AsInteger := iPrior;
        dmPedido.cdsConexaoTipoServico.AsString := sTpSer;
        dmPedido.cdsConexaoSequencia.AsInteger  := iSeq;
        dmPedido.cdsConexao.Post;
    except
        On e:Exception do
            WriteLogr('Erro ao inserir na tabela "cdsConexao". '+e.Message);
    end;
end;
begin
    sParte := fConexao;
    sParte2:= fConexao;
    iInicio := 0;
    i:=1;
    p:=0;
    sParte:= Copy(fConexao,iInicio,4);
    sParte2:=fConexao;
    try
            if  dmPedido.cdsConexao.Active = false then
                dmPedido.cdsConexao.CreateDataSet;
            dmPedido.cdsConexao.EmptyDataSet;
    Except
        on e:Exception do
            WriteLogr('Erro ao criar a tabela  temporária de conexão  '+e.Message);
    end;
    if (fConexao<>'') then
    begin
        repeat
            sParte2:=Copy(sParte2,6,length(sParte2));
            n := StrToInt(sParte[1]);
            S := sParte[2];
            E := sParte[3];
            p := StrToInt(sParte[4]);
            try
                InsereItemTamporario(StrToInt(E), sDNS[n], p, S, i);
            except
                on e:Exception do
                    WriteLogr('Erro ao inserir na tabela de conexão '+e.Message);
            end;
            sParte:= Copy(sParte2,iInicio,4);
            Inc(i)
        until sParte = '';
     end
     Else begin
          If dmPedido.tbCDs.Locate('CD_PRIN', 'CWB',[]) Then
          begin
              InsereItemTamporario(1, dmPedido.tbCDsCONEXAO1.AsString, 1, 'H', 1); //é o mesmo que dmPedido.tbCDsIP_WWW
              InsereItemTamporario(1, dmPedido.tbCDsCONEXAO2.AsString, 1, 'F', 2); //é o mesmo que dmPedido.tbCDsIP_WWW2
              InsereItemTamporario(1, dmPedido.tbCDsCONEXAO3.AsString, 2, 'F', 3); // e Contingencia sempre será ftp
     end
     else
          InsereItemTamporario(1, sDNS[2], 1, 'F', 1);
        //Para o caso da tabela estar vazia!
 end;
```

Comment: Desculpem-me 'o erro se apresenta', o correto é 'onde ocorre o erro'.

Comment: Todas as dependências estão na máquina onde o erro ocorre? Como está o SGBD nessas máquinas?

Comment: não tem sgbd, é tabela mesmo.... crio uma tabela temporária, com itens para conexão em vários itens como endereço dns, tipo de conexão (FTP ou HTTP) usuário e precedencia de conexão

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, você está fazendo o CreateDataSet, antes de inserir os dados temporários?

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, posta o código aqui, para gente pode ver como vc está criando o ClientDataSet

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro Segue parte do código, editei a pergunta, não consegui colocar no comentário (hehehe juvenil)

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, esse trecho não diz muito, em qual evento você está criando e qual dados você está preenchendo? Nomalmente o CreateDataSet é utilizado no evento OnCreate ou em algum método de inicialização.

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro, descobri o que é, o problema é abrir a DLL midas.dll, não sei o que ocorre mas na instalação não está atualizada com a que estou utilizando no desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

O componente TClientDataSet exige que a biblioteca **midas.dll** exista no sistema onde o programa será executado. Normalmente todas as máquinas de desenvolvimento já possuem esta biblioteca porque ela é instalada junto com o Delphi, mas é necessário distribuí-la juntamente com a aplicação desenvolvida.

Caso você não queira distribuir a biblioteca, você pode dispensar seu uso simplesmente incluindo na cláusula uses do seu projeto (dpr) a unit **MidasLib**. Esta unit (compilada num dcu) encapsula as funções que seriam executadas por midas.dll e por isso, ao incluí-la como indicado, dispensa sua distribuição